# Video File Size Optimization

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying the 2-pass technique of the FFmpeg in python but couldn't find any python tutorials do this task.
is there is no way instead of using Subprocess? if there's any illustrative example please provide me.

**Note:**

I have tried the 2-pass in the script like that:

```
input_fit  = {self.video_in:None}
output = {None:"-c:v h264 -b:v 260k -pass 1 -an -f mp4 NUL && ^",
          self.video_out:("ffmpeg -i \"%s\" -c:v h264 -b:v 260k -pass 2 " %self.video_in)}
         ## video_out IS The Name of The output File ##
model = FFmpeg(inputs = input_fit, outputs= output)
print(model.cmd)
```

It Raises an error of

> :: FFRuntimeError: exited with status 1,

but when i take the generated command and run it on the ffmpeg cmd it runs without errors and generates the video perfectly.
so anyone just could tell me what is the problem please?

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: @AMC Here it is :

FFRuntimeError: `ffmpeg -i "Timon & Pumbaa - Cute Moments Best Cartoon for Kids & Children Episodes 5 Part 1 - Alicia Miller.mp4" -c:v h264 -b:v 260k -pass 1 -an -f mp4 NUL && ^ ffmpeg -i "Timon & Pumbaa - Cute Moments Best Cartoon for Kids & Children Episodes 5 Part 1 - Alicia Miller.mp4" -c:v h264 -b:v 260k -pass 2 "Timon & Pumbaa - Cute Moments Best Cartoon for Kids & Children Episodes 5 Part 1 - Alicia Millerout.MP4"` exited with status 1

STDOUT:


STDERR: